# What's going on with this SQL Execution plan? Why does it gets *faster* when I ask for *more* rows? Why is it spooling so slowly?

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have a query that's returning the TOP N records after some slightly ugly CTE joining.

- I found that if I ran TOP 2431 records it would take ~30 seconds ...
- But if I ran the TOP 2432 records (i.e. 1 *additional* record) it only took <2 seconds ... :(

Eventually I realised this was because the statistics were out of date, and I updated the stats, cleared the plan caches, and got it working sensibly ... 2431 records returns in <2 seconds.

But then I tried a couple of other counts and found that 1500 records is also broken (29 seconds), and that the query plan is still broken in exactly the same way, despite now having completely fresh stats.

The difference between the fast and slow query execution plans appears to be roughly "Hash Match" (fast) vs "Lazy Table Spool"(slow):

Fast:
[image]

Slow:
[image]

*(The feed coming in from below is identical in each plan)*

*The Index scanned on `EnquiryLegs` is the `Booking` column; FK to the `Bookings` table.*

This was exactly the same difference previously in 2431 (slow; Table Spool) vs 2432 (fast; Hash Match)

What's going on, why does it use a so-much-worse Exec.Plan., and how do I fix it?

---

Full query.

*Yes, the CTE is gross, and I have plans to fix that separately. But clearly the query *can* run fine (well ... adequately .. 1.5 seconds is still very sad, but acceptable to the client for the time permitted) ... it just isn't doing so all the time*

```sql
WITH EarliestDepartureDates AS (SELECT EnquiryLegs.Booking,
                MIN(DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
                    Legs.DepartureYear,
                    Legs.DepartureMonth,
                    ISNULL(l.DepartureDay, 1),
                    ISNULL(l.DepartureTime, 0) / 100,
                    ISNULL(l.DepartureTime, 0) % 100, 0, 0)) AS [Date]
            FROM dbo.EnquiryLegs
            JOIN dbo.Legs ON Legs.ID = EnquiryLegs.ID
            GROUP BY EnquiryLegs.Booking)
SELECT TOP 1500 Bookings.ID, Bookings.foo, ... 
, CustomerContacts.ID, CustomerContacts.bar ...
, BaseContacts.FriendlyId, BaseContacts.baz...
FROM Bookings
LEFT JOIN CustomerContacts ON CustomerContacts.ID = Bookings.CustomerContact
LEFT JOIN BaseContacts ON BaseContacts.ID = CustomerContacts.ID
INNER JOIN EarliestDepartureDates ON EarliestDepartureDates.Booking = Bookings.ID
ORDER BY Bookings.CreatedAt DESC
```

"Updating the stats":

```sql
sp_updatestats

UPDATE STATISTICS Bookings WITH FULLSCAN
UPDATE STATISTICS EnquiryLegs WITH FULLSCAN
UPDATE STATISTICS BaseLegs WITH FULLSCAN

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('SQL Plans');
```

Comment: Are clustered indexes somehow forbidden in your company?

Comment: `.sqlplan` and `.xml` files are available for all of "Slow2431BeforeStatsFixed", "Fast2431AfterStatsFixed", "Slow1500".

Shout if any of those will be more useful than the above.

Comment: @siggemannen Errr .... actually yes. Would that explain it? Or is that merely a  observation? (I don't have a solid understanding of what the differences between spool and Match are)

Comment: And not "forbidden", per se ... just not used right here.

Comment: This codebase was previously using SQL Server Merge Replication, and GUID IDs, and I'm told that as part of that we "had to" use non-Clustered indexes for all of our Primary Indexes everywhere.

We no longer have Merge Replication (thank god) and "convert back to Clustered Indexes has been on the 'TechDebtThatCanBeFixedNowThatWeRemovedReplication'" to-not-get-done list for over 18 months (TD spend prohibited by client )

Comment: This looks like a common rowgoal issue. Often if you have a `TOP N ... ORDER BY` and there is an index that can provide that ordering then it might decide to use that index and do nested loops rather than some different execution strategy that involves a sort, but this can be catastrophically bad sometimes - especially if it has to read many more rows from the index than it expects before finding `N` matching ones to return

Comment: Did you mean to repeat `2431` in the description, as that makes no sense; if not then there's some threshold being exceeded?

Comment: Have you tried using option recompile? Aside, using table aliases would make your queries easier to read / maintain; you're running dbcc's above on a production server?!!

Comment: @Stu `you're running dbcc's above on a production server?!!` Oh god, no! :D This is on a development staging server; not even client-facing Testing.

Comment: @Stu `Did you mean to repeat 2431 in the description` No. ‍♂️ Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: `OPTION RECOMPILE` doesn't do anything. Indeed it seems to have made *something* worse ... as now 2431 is back to being 30seconds ... and can't fix it again - resetting the stats again, clearing the caches and running w/o RECOMPILE just sticks at 30s. :(

Comment: @MartinSmith that sounds broadly plausible ... is there anything one can do about it? Or is it just how SqlServer is sometimes?

Comment: You can provide indexing to make the nested loops more efficient. Or give a query hint disabling the rowgoal cost effect (DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL)

Comment: Please share execution plans using https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Please also show the tables and index definitions.

Comment: Merge replication should not prevent the use of clustered indexes.  In any event, now that you can use them, you should.  SQL's QP will do much better with covering indexes than without.  (meaning they include the columns required for the most common queries to be satisfied directly).    You are playing with bad stats and hoping that the estimates are right for a rowgoal problem, and this is the fundamental problems in your design/schema/query pattern.  Fix the indexes first.  (also reconsider GUID PKs).  Then consider your query pattern if things are still unstable.

Comment: As a workaround, you might try to change the query to `...EarliestDepartureDates INNER LOOP JOIN Booking...` to perhaps force the CTE to be materialized ahead of the JOIN.